# Date constants that are not fully specified

Tags: database, oracle, default-value, check-constraints

In Oracle what does **"date constants that are not fully specified."** mean?  Any examples?  It cannot be specified in the Check constraints and column default values according to the documentation.

Comment: Can you provide a link where you read this documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a line from [the documentation on CREATE TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_7002.htm).  I think what it means is that a  default date must be properly formatted.

So suppose we want a rule which defaults a date to the first day of the current year.  This is valid:

```
create table t1 (d1 date default to_date('01-JAN', 'DD-MON'));
```

whereas this statement ...

```
create table t1 (d1 date default to_date('01-JAN'));
```

... hurls`ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format`.

Comment: But isn't that true in any context?  An invalid date expression will never work, anywhere.  Why does the documentation only mention it in a few specific places?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10494087#10494087

**not fully specified** means date formats that could result in ambiguous or different values,

for example when it depends on other variables such as the RR format that depends on sysdate for the century data,

so '02-jan-12' could be '02-jan-1912' if the year in sysdate is 1900
and could be 2012 if sysdates year is 2000

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is wrong.  You *can* use a date constant that is not fully specified, in a constraint or a default.  And even a "fully specified" date constant may still fail in some cases.  I'm not sure exactly what the documentation means, but I think the real issue here is the classic Oracle problem of assuming a date format.

The `DEFAULT` clause does not store a value, it stores an expression that will be evaluated to a value each time it is used.

If you do something silly like:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD';
create table date_test(a number, b date default '01');
```

It will work, for a while:

```
insert into date_test(a) values (1);
select b from date_test;

B
--
01
```

But if someone uses a different date format, it will crash just for them:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
insert into date_test(a) values (1);

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
```

Note that a fully specified, unambiguous expression, can still cause problems.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
create table date_test2(a number, b date default to_date('01-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
alter session set nls_language = 'FRENCH';
insert into date_test(a) values(1);

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01840: valeur entrΘe pas assez longue pour le format de la date
```

What's wrong with 01-JAN-2000?  Not everyone know what "JAN" is.

```
SQL> select to_char(date '2000-01-01', 'MON') from dual;

TO_CH
-----
JANV.
```

**The real moral of this story**

If you want to use a date literal, always use the [ANSI date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ): `DATE '2000-01-01'`